# Query children by name and return parents if found

Tags: mysql, join

I have a table structure like so:

```
locationID     locationName    parentID
     1            Europe           0
     2            England          1
     3             Kent            2
```

I'm querying the table by name, so if i search for Kent. I want it to return Europe > England > Kent as the search result.

Can anyone point me in the direction for the right query. Is it a left join on the same table?

Comment: How many level are looking to check? Just three?

Comment: Could be more, maybe 6 or 7

Comment: You'll need a stored procedure then

Comment: Although the [adjacency list model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list) is more intuitive to those new to trees and hierarchies, the [nested sets model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) might be a better fit if the levels are deep and varied, considering mySQL doesn't have good support for iterative queries. Hard to say without further analysis e.g. how stable is the data (I mean, England isn't going to leave Europe anytime soon, right??)

Comment: MySQL has native support for recursion. Choices include writing a sproc, [outer] joining the table to itself as often as could be required, handling the logic in application code, or switching to another model (i.e. nested sets)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL doesn't provide native support for a recursive query.

For a set "maximum" number of levels in the hierarchy, it is possible to write a query.

As an example:

```
 SELECT g0.locationName
      , g1.locationName
      , g2.locationName
      , g3.locationName
      , g4.locationName
      , g5.locationName
      , g6.locationName
   FROM mytable g0
   LEFT JOIN mytable g1 ON g1.locationId = g0.parentId
   LEFT JOIN mytable g2 ON g2.locationId = g1.parentId
   LEFT JOIN mytable g3 ON g3.locationId = g2.parentId
   LEFT JOIN mytable g4 ON g4.locationId = g3.parentId
   LEFT JOIN mytable g5 ON g5.locationId = g4.parentId
   LEFT JOIN mytable g6 ON g6.locationId = g5.parentId
  WHERE g0.locationName = 'Kent'
```

This approach can be extended to a larger number of levels, g7, g8, g9. But the query will impose a maximum number of levels to be traversed.

The query doesn't do any checks for a "loop". For example if "Europe" has parentId that references "Kent", that would be a loop in the hierarchy. The query doesn't do anything to check for that condition, it just follows the link to the parent, and around and around it will go.

To allow for a dynamic number of levels, to get that to work in MySQL, that would require a MySQL stored program (PROCEDURE) with some conditional logic; to implement a more recursive approach.

Answer (score 0):

If the hierarchy can only go down till 3 levels then yes, you can use `self join` to get the required data, e.g.:

```
SELECT l3.locationName, l2.locationName, l1.locationName
FROM location l1 JOIN location l2 ON l1.locationID = l2.parentId
JOIN location l3 ON l2.locationID = l3.parentID
WHERE l3.locationName = 'Kent';
```

Comment: what if there's more levels?

Comment: You can add more joins if there are more level.